# Firefox specific html5 video error

Tags: html, firefox

Using the html5 video player, I get the following error in firefox

Error Msg: No video with the supported format and mimetype found

Passing Tests: Chrome / Safari / IE

Code:

```
<video preload="metadata" controls="">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="https://subdomain.clientURL.mp4"></source>
            Your browser does not support the video t…
</video>
```

Http Response Mime Type:

```
Request Method:GETStatus Code:206 Partial Content
Host: redacted.s3.amazonaws.com
Content-Length:405838
Content-Range:bytes 0-405837/405838
Content-Type:video/mp4
Server:AmazonS3
```

Comment: Did you get solution? I am having same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Firefox only supports mp4 if it's installed on the operating system.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats#Browser_compatibility) MP4 support is not built into Firefox due to patent issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can add more than one source path in a video tag with different MIME types. I have tested that, MIME type 'video/mp4' is working in another browser but not in firefox so for firefox you have to convert your video into '.ogg' format and add it to the same source location. Then you can specify a video tag like below to target different MIME types.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="abc.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="abc.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

When you run this code, browser will automatically select suitable MIME type and fetch the particular video from your source location so 'abc.mp4' is considered for chrome, edge, and internet explorer and abc.ogg will be for firefox.

You don't need to install adobe flash player to play this video in firefox browser. I have tested this code in firefox's version 71.0.1, I hope this can help. **Happy Coding...**